# AS function not working in LARAVEL database statement

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-query-builder, laravel-6

I want to join two tables in my Laravel project but any same field name in two tables i use.

User table:

- id
- name
- gender

Gender table:

- id
- name

So i create join function in Controller like this:

```
$account = DB::table('users')
                            ->join('genders','genders.id', '=','users.gender')
                            ->select('users.*','genders.*','users.id as users_id','users.name as users_name','genders.id as genders_id','genders.name as genders_name')
                            ->where('users.id',$id)->get()->first();
```

And in my blade i use this to get field name in users table:

```
{{ $account->users_name }}
```

But i got an error notification like this:

> Trying to get property 'users_name' of non-object

Anyone can help me how should i do? thanks.

Comment: still not working @SalmanZafar

Answer (score 0):

**Use name instead of user_name**

Try to debug the code using **print_r()** there are two different array will be there who have same fields
so if you want to use user name then your code should be like this

```
{{ $account->name }}
```

if you want gender name then name should be inside the gender array so u can use gender name like below in blade file

```
{{ $account->genders['name'] }}
```

**Edit above code**

```
$account = DB::table('users')
                            ->join('genders','genders.id', '=','users.gender')
                            ->select('users.*','genders.*','users.id as users_id','users.name as users_name','genders.id as genders_id','genders.name as genders_name')
                            ->where('users.id',$id)->first();
```

Comment: can you please tell me what are you getting in $account?

Answer (score 0):

It seems such record was not found in database - that's why you are getting this error because `$account` is null.

Make sure that query generates valid result and in view add condition before displaying account like this:

```
@if ($account)
   // here display account
@endif
```

or in your controller change

```
->first()
```

into

```
->firstOrFail()
```

in case you don't want further action when account was not found.

And in fact instead of:

```
->where('users.id',$id)->get()->first()
```

you can just use:

```
->where('users.id',$id)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your user don't have genders record,

try to use left join:

```php
$account = DB::table('users')
                            ->leftjoin('genders','genders.id', '=','users.gender')
                            ->select('users.*','genders.*','users.id as users_id','users.name as users_name','genders.id as genders_id','genders.name as genders_name')
                            ->where('users.id',$id)->first();
```

Comment: that's work, but if use leftjoin, i can't display `{{ $account->genderrs_name }}`

Comment: @AbuUbaidillah because there is no user' gender reference to gender

Comment: @AbuUbaidillah you need to add a gender for the user with `$id`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting multiple records if you use `get()` method.

> using get();

```
$accounts = DB::table('users')
           ->join('genders','genders.id', '=','users.gender')
           ->select('users.*','genders.*','users.id as users_id','users.name as users_name','genders.id as genders_id','genders.name as genders_name')
           ->where('users.id',$id)->get();
```

**Blade file**

```
@foreach($accounts as $account)
    {{ $account->users_name }}
@endforeach
```

> using first() you'll get only one collection.

```
$accounts = DB::table('users')
           ->join('genders','genders.id', '=','users.gender')
           ->select('users.*','genders.*','users.id as users_id','users.name as users_name','genders.id as genders_id','genders.name as genders_name')
           ->where('users.id',$id)->first();
```

**Blade file**

```
{{ $account->users_name }}
```